# How do I filter an array of objects by keyword using LoDash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have an array of objects like this:

```
[{
  away: "Seattle Seahawks",
  home: "Kansas City Chiefs",
},
{
  away: "Houston Texans",
  home: "San Francisco 49ers",
},
{
  away: "Dallas Cowboys",
  home: "Los Angeles Rams",
}]
```

Requirements:

Search every object and for the keyword `49er` and have it return object #2.

Search every object for the keyword `cow` and have it return object #3.

Search every object for the keyword `an` and have it return all three objects.

What would be the best way to achieve this in lodash?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution with `_.flow`:

```
const my_arr = [{
  away: "Seattle Seahawks",
  home: "Kansas City Chiefs",
},
{
  away: "Houston Texans",
  home: "San Francisco 49ers",
},
{
  away: "Dallas Cowboys",
  home: "Los Angeles Rams",
}]

function flowFilter(array, substr) {
    return _.filter(array, _.flow(
    _.identity,
    _.values,
    _.join,
    _.toLower,
    _.partialRight(_.includes, substr)
  ));
}

const one = flowFilter(my_arr, '49er');
const two = flowFilter(my_arr, 'cow');
const three = flowFilter(my_arr, 'an');

console.log('one', one);
console.log('two', two);
console.log('three', three);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/1321mzjw/

Answer (score 2):

No need of lodash library use native JavaScript methods.

```js
var data = [{
  away: "Seattle Seahawks",
  home: "Kansas City Chiefs",
}, {
  away: "Houston Texans",
  home: "San Francisco 49ers",
}, {
  away: "Dallas Cowboys",
  home: "Los Angeles Rams",
}];

console.log(
  // filter the array
  data.filter(function(v) {
    // get all keys of the object
    return Object.keys(v)
    // iterate and check for any object property value cotains the string
    .some(function(k) {
      // convert to lowercase(to make it case insensitive) and check match
      return v[k].toLowerCase().indexOf('49ers') > -1;
    })
  })
);

console.log(
  data.filter(function(v) {
    return Object.keys(v).some(function(k) {
      return v[k].toLowerCase().indexOf('an') > -1;
    })
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use plain javascript as well.

```
const my_arr = [{
  away: "Seattle Seahawks",
  home: "Kansas City Chiefs",
},
{
  away: "Houston Texans",
  home: "San Francisco 49ers",
},
{
  away: "Dallas Cowboys",
  home: "Los Angeles Rams",
}]



const filterByText = (arr, text) => {
  return arr.filter((item) => (
    !(
      item.away.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === -1 && 
      item.home.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) === -1
    )
  )
)}

console.log(filterByText(my_arr, '49er')) // #2
console.log(filterByText(my_arr, 'cow')) // #3
console.log(filterByText(my_arr, 'an')) // #1, #2, #3
```

Using lodash in this case would be nearly similar because you are requiring toLoverCase to be used.

```
const filterByText = (arr, text) => {

  return _.filter(arr, (obj) => { 
    return Object.keys(obj).some((key) =>
      return obj[key].toLowerCase().indexOf(text) !== -1;
    )
  }

)}
```

Answer (score 1):

the shortest i can think of is

```js
// lodash
data.filter(d => _.some(d, t => /cow/i.test(t)))

// plain js
data.filter(d => Object.keys(d).some(k => /cow/i.test(d[k])))
```

Answer (score 0):

I like combining regular expressions with lodash functions. This scenario is applicable. Create a generic function that accepts a collection and a `RegExp` to search with:

```
function myFilter(coll, regex) {
  return _.filter(
    coll,
    _.unary(_.partialRight(_.some, _.method('match', regex)))
  );
}
```

Now you can pass whatever regular expression you want to `myFilter()`, and it will test against all property values of each object in `coll`. Here's how to use it:

```
myFilter(data, /49er/);
// ➜ [
//     {
//       away: "Houston Texans",
//       home: "San Francisco 49ers",
//     }
//   ]

myFilter(data, /cow/i);
// ➜ [
//     {
//       away: "Dallas Cowboys",
//       home: "Los Angeles Rams",
//     }
//   ]

myFilter(data, /an/);
// ➜ [
//     {
//       away: "Seattle Seahawks",
//       home: "Kansas City Chiefs",
//     },
//     {
//       away: "Houston Texans",
//       home: "San Francisco 49ers",
//     },
//     {
//       away: "Dallas Cowboys",
//       home: "Los Angeles Rams",
//     }
//   ]
```

Here's a summary of the lodash functions used:

- [filter()](https://lodash.com/docs#filter): Filters a collection by evaluating a predicate function on each item.
- [unary()](https://lodash.com/docs#unary): Makes a function only accept the first argument, ignoring all others.
- [partialRight()](https://lodash.com/docs#partialRight): Partially-applies function arguments from the right. When the resulting function is called with more arguments, they go to the left.
- [some()](https://lodash.com/docs#some): True if any of the items in the collection evaluate to true for the given predicate.
- [method()](https://lodash.com/docs#method): Invokes the method name on a given object argument. Also accepts arguments to partially-apply.